# PHP Show Source Code Instead of .html File

Tags: php

I'm sorry if the title is a bit confusing, but this is my problem: 
I need to echo the source of a .html file using PHP. I tried using PHP include(); while the file's extensions were .html.txt, but that showed up as if it is . When I access the file directly, for example "example.com/file.html.txt", it shows up as a normal .txt. 
This is the PHP code I'm using to display the file:

```
<div>
<?php
include "../head.php";
$path = $_GET["p"];
?>
<div style="position:absolute; top:90px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:10px;">

<?php
echo "<code>";
include("files/".$path);
echo "</code>";
?>

</div>
```

I hope I'm understandable! :) Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I smell a gaping security hole in your code. `?p=../../../some/uploaded/file/containing/malicious/php/code`

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to use `<pre>`, not `<code>`.

Comment: if the content of the file you are displaying needs to be processed by php first, use my method, otherwise, use one of the file get contents methods or love's method. and whaetver you do, do not put this code on the internet as it is a severe security hole.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've learned bunches from all of you! :D

Comment: `highlight_file($file, true);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `include()`, read the contents of the file and print them instead (don't forget to escape).

In your case `$path` is user input, you should make sure that no sensitive informatin can be accessed. Using [`basename($path);`](http://php.net/basename) makes sure that no directory traversal is possible.

```
<code>
<?php
    // $path = basename($path);
    $html = file_get_contents("files/".$path);
    echo htmlspecialchars($html);
?>
</code>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to output HTML tags in an html file, use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape special characters.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest wrapping it inside a **textarea**. Simple and quick.

```
echo "<textarea>";
include "/filename.txt";
echo "</textarea>";
```

Sometimes, when we're looking for something very simple, we overlook the obvious. **:o)**

Answer (score 2):

if you want to be able to see html source in a browser, the best method would be to run it through the function htmlentities() or like. the tricky part is getting the file contents of the include into a string so that you can do that. for this we use ob_start() and ob_get_clean(). these basically start an output buffer, then get the contents of the output buffer so you can process it and echo it.

```
<div>
<?php
include "../head.php";
$path = $_GET["p"];
?>
<div style="position:absolute; top:90px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:10px;">

<?php
echo "<code>";
ob_start();
include("files/".$path);
echo htmlentities(ob_get_clean());
echo "</code>";
?>

</div>
```

Comment: @ColeJohnson yes, agreed. that would be more efficient haha. however if the include file is .php, this may be necessary to get the content processed, although this would also be rather dangerous security wise.

Answer (score 1):

Include is not safe. If your file has PHP code it will be executed.
You should rather use this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('yourfile.html'));
```