# how to read source by RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want help in this problem

this command not work good can u help me

i have new folder on my website under this name

"TextPHP"

and i put this code in .htaccess

RewriteRule ^(.*) /home/myhome/public_html/$1.php [L,T=text/plain]

i want any one go to that folder can read any source from my php files

and this not work

i try H=text/plain

and i got error 500

also i try 

  php_value engine off


  php_value engine off

not working :(

its there any other trick

and sorry about my english language so bad :p

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the full path to the file in the rewrite rule, what you are specifiying is a new absolute URL or a URI relative to the web root.  So if you want to make any URI go to a PHP file of teh same name, here is how you would do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.php [L]
```

No need to specify `/home/myhome/public_html` here.

This is a basic example however, as typically, this is much too broad of a rule, as it would prevent you from serving up images or other actual files from the web root (they would all end up with `.php` appended to the.  So assuming this is actually what you want, you would commonly see something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.php [L]
```

This rule applies in cases when the URI does not match an actual filename or directory.  Thus requests to `/some_file.php` would not be redirected to `/some_file.php.php`.

Comment: also not work :( 
my site example.com and i have many php files on it
i want if one access to example.com/source/FileName.php read source for example.com/FileName.php as text file

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your webserver to show the source for `*.phps` files (e.g. make symlinks) with:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Or to disable PHP processing for that directory completely use:

```
RemoveHandler .php 
RemoveType .php
```

Alternatively or additionally with:

```
php_flag engine off
```

On some setups (cgi / fastcgi) even:

```
Options -ExecCGI
```

If you wanna use mod_rewrite, then write a wrapper script for displaying them via `readfile()` (and some basename() filtering for security) and apply it like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)$ showsrc.php?file=$1
```

Comment: see my site http://example.com/ and i have over 400 php file on this site i want every one enter to http://example.com/source/FileName.php read source of http://example.com/FileName.php

Comment: Then you'll need said wrapper script, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693873/php-show-source-code-instead-of-html-file for an example. The `basename()` thing is super crucial!